# Getting a user's groups from LDAP in Spring Boot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, ldap, spring-security-ldap

Our legacy application is deployed on Glassfish, and uses `javax.security` to manage authorization.

The following code retrieves from `LDAP` the Active Director groups the user is a member of:

```
try{
    subject = (Subject) PolicyContext.getContext("javax.security.auth.Subject.container");  
    Principal principal; 
    if (subject != null) {
        Iterator<Principal> principalsIt = subject.getPrincipals().iterator(); 
        while (principalsIt.hasNext()) { 
            principal = principalsIt.next(); 
            ldapGroups.add(principal.toString());
        } 
    } 
}catch (PolicyContextException e) {
    ...
}
```

In our new Spring Boot application, after login, we can use the Spring `SecurityContextHolder` to get user details:

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
String currentPrincipalName = authentication.getName();
```

This is how the user is being authenticated and authorized:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    private RedirectStrategy redirectStrategy = new DefaultRedirectStrategy();

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.ldapAuthentication().userSearchFilter("(...)")
                .userSearchBase("...")
                .groupSearchBase("...").groupSearchFilter("member={0}").contextSource()
                .url("...").managerDn("...").managerPassword("...");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity security) throws Exception {
        security.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/*/**").permitAll().anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated().and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, "/campaigns/myCampaigns");
                    }
                });

    }
}
```

Is there a way to modify the code which logs the user in, so that at the same time that they are authenticated and authorized, it also retrieves their groups at the same time. So far, the only examples I have found involve the use of `LdapTemplate` and making a separate call.

Thanks

Comment: there is too little information, how is the userdetails object built, how do you fetch the user in the spring boot application, etc. Voted to close needs more debugging details.

Comment: Edited question, hope it add what you want. Thank you very much.

Comment: so you are basically asking us to solve your problem. What have you tried? i don't even see any code of you even trying please read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users have you even read the documentation?